# RPC remote server hostname

Tags: c, rpc

I wrote a RPC program and ran the server on my own machine. Now when I started  my client and passed my own hostname as 'ak-pc'(output of uname -n) into clnt_create, an error appeared which said

```
ak-pc: RPC: Unknown protocol
```

Any ideas about what the function wants? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I was just implementing the program [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node34.html) and I run the server and client both on the same machine.

Comment: What is your program's source? That error message is less than descriptive. What are you passing to `cint_create()`?

Comment: @cyphar...edited the question specifying the source